# SQL query to remove the duplicates across rows

Tags: sql

I have a table as follows:

```
City1 City2 Distance
A      B     500
C      D     400
E      F     800
F      E     800
```

My output should be as follows:

```
City1 City2 Distance
A      B     500
C      D     400
E      F     800
```

Can you pls help me write a sql for this?

Order of the cities does not matter. Only one unique combination is required.
here (F,E,800) will also do in the final output.

Comment: Why keep `E,      F` and not `F,      E`? what is logic ?

Comment: @jarlh SELECT DISTINCT was my first thought too but i noticed that the cities are inverted in the "duplicate" so i think he needs something more than that

Comment: We can keep F,E, order does not matter, what matters is we should keep unique pairs

Comment: @jarlh distinct wont work here

Comment: @Jogesh if you add your last comment to the question, it may help others

Comment: What is the logic for _which_ distance value you retain should duplicate pairs occur?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Distance is same for duplicate pairs

Comment: @Jogesh Then my answer stands as being one way of approaching this.

Comment: @Doruk, oops, you're right! (Didn't read carefully enough.)

Comment: @UberGrunk, oops, you're right! (Didn't read carefully enough.)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to remove duplicate pairs of any two cities, regardless of the order in which those cities appear.  What is not clear is which `Distance` value you want to retain.  Assuming you are OK with retaining the largest distance, you can try the following query:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN City1 < City2 THEN City1 ELSE City2 END AS City1,
    CASE WHEN City2 < City1 THEN City1 ELSE City2 END AS City2,
    MAX(Distance) AS Distance
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN City1 < City2 THEN City1 ELSE City2 END,
    CASE WHEN City2 < City1 THEN City2 ELSE City1 END
```

Note that I gave as generic an answer as possible, because you never told us which version of SQL you are using.  This query could be simplified somewhat in MySQL, Postgres, and a few others.

Here is a running demo in MySQL:

## Rextester

Comment: A true generic answer would be ANSI SQL compliant, which allows nothing but column names in the GROUP BY clause. (Use a derived table!)

Comment: I believe the above query would run across major RDBMS, which is probably what the OP is using.  But thanks for letter me know of the ANSI standard for `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
;

WITH cte
AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY /* based on what? can be multiple columns*/
        ORDER BY (
                SELECT 0
                )
        ) RN
FROM yourtable
)
DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use `case` expressions to always put first City in first column, and last city in second column. Then do `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicate rows:

```
select distinct case when City1 < City2 then City1 else City2 end,
                case when City1 > City2 then City1 else City2 end,
                distance
from tablename
```

Comment: It should be noted that often `DISTINCT` is implemented under the hood using `GROUP BY` (q.v. the answer I gave here).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, that may be true for some products, but not for all. (Less optimal implementation, I'd say.)

Answer (score 0):

One method that works well across databases *and* guarantees that the only values in the output are in the original table is to use `union all`:

```
select t.*
from t
where city1 < city2
union all
select t.*
from t
where city1 > city2 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.city1 = t1.city2 and t2.city2 = t1.city1
                 );
```

Note that if you have duplicates in the table, you should use `union` rather than `union all`.  Also, you might need to take the distance into account, if they can differ.